# Nexus repo not showing

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, nexus3

I'm new in nexus and jenkins. I have a basic maven project on github and tried to create ci/cd pipeline with nexus repo.
But nexus repo not showing it says: no components/assets found in this repository.
here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>springboot</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>repackage</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>Uber</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

here is my stage of jenkins pipeline:

```
 stage('upload war file to nexus3'){
            steps{
                script{
                    nexusArtifactUploader artifacts: 
                    [
                        [
                            artifactId: 'springboot', classifier: '', file: 'target/Uber.jar', type: 'jar'
                        ]
                    ], 
                    credentialsId: 'nexus-auth', 
                    groupId: 'com.example', 
                    nexusUrl: 'localhost:8081', 
                    nexusVersion: 'nexus3', 
                    protocol: 'http',
                    repository: 'demoapp-release', 
                    version: '1.0.0'
                }
            }
        }
```

output of pipeline : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZensM.jpg

but i can't see my repo on repository manager. I checked my credentials and syntax.
What am i missing, any advice?